# Mime encoded headers with extra '=' (==?utf-8?b?base64string?=)

Tags: parsing, encoding, character-encoding, protocols, mime

*This might be a silly question but... here it goes!*

I wrote my own MIME parser in native C++. It's a nightmare with the encodings! It was stable for the last 3 months or so but recently I noticed this `Subject: header`.

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?T2ZpY2luYSBkZSBJbmZvcm1hY2nDs24sIEluaWNpYXRpdmFzIHkgUmVjbGFt?===?UTF-8?B?YWNpb25lcw==?=
```

which should decode to this:

```
Subject: Oficina de Información, Iniciativas y Reclamaciones
```

The problem is there is one extra `= (equal)` in there which I can't figure out binding the two *(why 2?)* encoded elements which I don't understand why are separated. In theory the format should be: `=?charset?encoding?encoded_string?=` but found another subject that starts with two `=`.

```
==?UTF-8?B?blahblahlblah?=
```

**How should I handle the extra `=`?**

I could replace `==?` with `=?` *(which I am)* before doing anything *(and it works)*... but I'm wondering if there's any kind of spec regarding this so I don't hack my way into proper functionality.

**PS**: *How much I hate these relic protocols! All text communications should be UTF-8 and XML :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MIME headers encoded words are used (RFC 2047 Section 2.).

> ... (why 2?)

To overcome 75 encoded word limit, which is there because of 78 line length limit (or to use 2 different encodings like Chinese and Polish for example).

RFC 2047:

> An 'encoded-word' may not be more than 75 characters long,
>   including    'charset', 'encoding', 'encoded-text', and delimiters. 
>   If it is    desirable to encode more text than will fit in an
>   'encoded-word' of    75 characters, multiple 'encoded-word's
>   (separated by CRLF SPACE) may be used.

Here's the example from RFC2047 (note there is no '=' in between):

```
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?B?SWYgeW91IGNhbiByZWFkIHRoaXMgeW8=?=
  =?ISO-8859-2?B?dSB1bmRlcnN0YW5kIHRoZSBleGFtcGxlLg==?=
```

Your subject should be decoded as:

```
"Oficina de Información, Iniciativas y Reclam=aciones"
```

**mraq** answer is incorrect. Soft line breaks apply to 'Quoted Printable' Content-Transfer-Encoding only, which can be used in MIME body.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the [MIME RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html) double equal signs are not valid input (for encoding), but keep in mind you could interpret the first equal sign as what it is and then use the following stuff for decoding. But seriously, those extra equal signs look like artifacts, maybe from an incorrect encoder.

Comment: I think so too. I've seen them on 5 emails from different sources and thought it was something I was missing. And what better place to ask than SO ):

Answer (score 0):

It is called the "**Soft Line Break**" and it is the heritage of the SMTP protocol.

Quoting page 20 of [RFC2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt)

> (Soft Line Breaks) The Quoted-Printable encoding
>             REQUIRES that encoded lines be no more than 76
>             characters long.  If longer lines are to be encoded
>             with the Quoted-Printable encoding, "soft" line breaks
>             must be used.  An equal sign as the last character on a
>             encoded line indicates such a non-significant ("soft")
>             line break in the encoded text.

And also [Wikipedia on Quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

> A soft line break consists of an "=" at the end of an encoded line,
>   and does not appear as a line break in the decoded text.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It is confusing  'Quoted Printable' Content-Transfer-Encoding (RFC 2045) with 'Q-encoded' encoded words (RFC 2047). The subject above should be decoded as "Oficina de Información, Iniciativas y Reclam=aciones"